# Table with different size of rows

Tags: tables

I want to draw a table like the following:

[image]

but the best I can do is

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
a & b&c\\
\midrule
a & b&c\\
a & b&c\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & C&H\\\cline{2-3}
&D&I\\\cline{2-3}
&E&L\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{B} & F&M\\\
&G&N\\\cline{2-3}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or  without multirow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|}
\hline
A & C&H\\\cline{2-3}
&D&I\\\cline{2-3}
&E&L\\
\hline
B & F&M\\\cline{2-3}
&G&N\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look to the multirow package. PS: please next time post a MWE together with your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    a & b & c\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{a} & b & c \\
    & d & e\\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{a} & b & c \\
    & d & e\\
    & f & g\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```